# sharing data with popToViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

my app crash with this message

```
011-02-22 00:12:30.422 test01[6246:207] -[RootViewController setString1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x623c800
2011-02-22 00:12:30.423 test01[6246:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RootViewController setString1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x623c800'
```

*** Call stack at first throw:

this is my code:

```
- (void)save2:(id)sender{


(pseudoUtilisateur *) [pseudoUtilTb cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
self.string =textField.text;
NSLog(@"donnees %@",string);


AvisUtilisateur *avs = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
avs.string1 = self.string;


[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

i dont understand why  it told me RootviewController setString1. ?

thx

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
avs.string1 = self.string;
```

is translated by the compiler into this:

```
[avs setString1:[self string]];
```

You defined `avs` as `AvisUtilisateur *avs` so you're assuming the root view controller (the object at index 0 in the navigation controller's array of view controllers) is an instance of `AvisUtilisateur`. Whether or not that's correct, your code assumes that the root view controller has a `readwrite` property named `string1`, and apparently that's not the case.

Comment: hi

thanks for answer me. but i don't understand why i have to declare a string1 in my rootViewControll. i don't want to share data in the rootViewController.
Maybe because i use a

    [self.navigationController.viewControllers] ?

i have 3 classes : rootViewController, AvisUtilisateur and PseudoUtilisateur.

i want to share data between PseudoUtilisateur and AvisUtilisateur.


thx

Comment: Your code is sending a `setString1:` message to an instance of your custom class `RootViewController`, which is the object at index 0 inside the navigation controller. Perhaps you were expecting that to be an instance of `AvisUtilisatuer`, but it's not.